# Create 2 Instances of Java App?

Tags: java, networking, instance

I am building a Java networking app, and would like to be able to demonstrate the networking capabilities (over localhost) for users that do not have 2 computers to test it on.

I am wondering if there is a way, possibly by calling the main method again, to create another instance of a Java app. This can not just be another instance of the JFrame, as the networking capabilities would not function correctly.

Example Scenario: User clicks on "Demo Mode", then app creates a second instance, then user can do test the network connection over localhost.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without two computers, you should at least run your app twice (on the same computer) instead of having a special "Demo Mode" that uses the same JVM.

All you may need to do is add some configuration so they don't interfere with eachother (such as configuring server socket ports or local disk file locations).

Another (only slightly more involved once you get the hang of it) option is to use virtual machines (such as VirtualBox) to fake two actual computers with a network connection in between.

Comment: They are configured not to run into each other. Is there a way that I can call a function which access the file on the hard drive, and runs the file again in its own JVM?

Comment: No, just start the whole program twice, in separate JVM. Same as you would on two machines.

Comment: You could make another program (or just a shell script) to automated this startup. But don't mix the "Demo Mode" bootstrapping into your main application code.

Comment: So, if I were to open 2 apps within the same JVM instance, they would not be sandboxed, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Jake,

If you absolutely cannot accomplish this by running two instances of your program at the same time, can you try running a virtual machine on your computer? Try running your program on your desktop as is, then run it again in a virtual machine that has Java on it.

Stacking the JVM on top of another virtual machine shouldn't be a big deal if it is just simple program. However, I wouldn't count on it for performance if it is a resource hungry program.

EDIT: I prefer VirtualBox
https://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that does exactly the same thing as your main and call that method twice. Or you can use run the same program on separate JVMs.